# Command to see previous code using SVN

Tags: svn, ubuntu, command-line

What is the command to see or go back (but not revert) any of our previous codes(last 3 or 5) using svn. I know there is such command `revert` but this is not what I'm searching for because I only want to see how does the previous code look like and not to revert it. How do I do this via command line in UNIX-like system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn cat will display the contents of a file.

You can see the previous version by using the -r switch to specifiy the revision.

For example

```
svn cat http://myrepo/myfile.txt -r1
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

[Subversion Commands and Scripts](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Subversion.html)

```
svn diff -rBASE:HEAD
```

---

```
right click on file go to svn >> check Difference
```

[**Revision Log Dialog**](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-2)